# Иконка в CSS неправильно выделяется

Tags: html, css

[image: Иконка с неправильным выделением]

код иконки

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
font-family: icomoon !important;
speak: never;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

}

> я бы хотел поправить выделение иконки

Comment: А зачем пользователю выделять иконку?

Comment: я просто думаю это баг же? я верно понимаю ?

Comment: Давайте так, логично подумайте, почему это баг? Что такое баг? То что вы хотите "исправить" это баг?

Comment: Ну если у объекта не правленое выделение это баг